# Problem in allocating memory for structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure, procedural-programming

I have structure t_REC_instance and I want to create an instance and allocate memory for its variables. 
I am doing something wrong. In the commented space it gives sigINT error when debugging. Can some one point me what am i doing wrong.c

```
typedef struct sAppRecipe
{
    union
    {
    struct sAppBread
        {
            int sugar_qty;
            int salt_qty;

        }tAppBread;
    struct sAppPancake
        {
            int sugar_qty1;
        }tAppPancake;
    };

}tAppRecipe;

typedef struct sAppRecipe tAppRecipe;


struct sREC_instance
{
    tAppRecipe *currentRecipe;
    tAppRecipe *newRecipe;
    tAppRecipe *updateRecipe;
};
typedef struct sREC_instance t_REC_instance;






tAppRecipe *REC_Alloc(void) {
    return malloc(sizeof (tAppRecipe));
}

t_REC_instance *instance;   // 

int REC_createInstance1(t_REC_instance *instance)
{

    instance->currentRecipe =REC_Alloc();      // there is a problem here
    if (!instance->currentRecipe)
        {
            printf("not allocated");
        }
}



void main()
{
REC_createInstance1(instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

`instance->currentRecipe =REC_Alloc();`

is a problem because you're accessing the `currentRecipe` member of `instance` which doesn't exist; `instance` is not pointing anywhere, so you need to allocate it first:

`instance = malloc(sizeof(t_REC_instance));`

Comment: Hi @Reticulated Spline , i need a little more help. I am trying to understand pointer here.           I am calling   REC_DestroyInstance(instance); after creating  and when I enter the function I do not see the memory address allocated by REC_CreateInstance(instance);  . ie the address of the instance inside REC_DestroyInstance(instance) function is 0x00 and not the address created? will the address not be available through out the program ?

Comment: @madhumadi please create another question as this is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Fix:**

Your code is assigning the `currentRecipe` member of the struct pointed to by `instance`, but `instance` is not set to anything, that means it's pointing to some invalid portion of memory which is causing the error.

Change this line:

```
t_REC_instance *instance;
```

to

```
t_REC_instance instance;
```

and this line:

```
REC_createInstance1(instance);
```

to

```
REC_createInstance1(&instance);
```